# powershell - show last event after filter with pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the last event (with a certain event ID and a certain word in the message field). The code I use:

```
Get-WinEvent @{logname = 'security';id=4663} | ? {$_.Message -like "*WriteData (or AddFile)*"}
```

My issue is that it finds multiple events and I only want to get the newest.
I know I can use `-MaxEvents 1` (after sorting it by date) but I would need to place it after the pipeline (because I want the newest event after the `Message` filtering).

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the  `? {}` runs by default the `process block`. You cloud explicitly add an `end block` and run your code there. You can also use `& {}` instead of `? {}` and the variables will be globally available after your function has finished. It might only work for things in the `begin block`, not sure right now.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. sorry i didn't understand what you mean, all those shortcuts are confusing me. could you paste the code you think should work?

Comment: that is correct. but the MaxEvent parameter belongs to the Get-WinEvent cmlet. it wont be helpful if i place it after the Get-WinEvent cmlet because i need to apply the 'Message' filter first (the part after the pipeline) and only then make it show me only the newest event.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to be a simple `Select-Object`.

I first forced it to be sorted by time with `Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending` and then piped it to `Select-Object -First 1`.

The whole thing looks like this:

`Get-WinEvent @{logname = 'security';id=4663} | ? {$_.Message -like "*WriteData (or AddFile)*"} | Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Yes I understand the problem now. It's early XD. Still looking for a build in way though. Anyways good job.